# Create users - React, Firebase cloud functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a react app with authentication and using firebase cloud functions. I'm also using customClaims to set user roles such as admin, moderators, editors and users. I also have a firestore doc where i store userinfo like company info and so on, and i have a function for admins (myself) to create other users.

But how do i do if  i want to allow the moderators to create users but only allow them to create users connected to their own company. They should be able to set editors and even moderators for their own company but not be able to create users for another company.

I know that im able on the client to pass the user info directly based on their own user profile that is loaded to the new user. But that might be a bit of a security issue right? The best way, as i understand it, would be to automaticaly add the info in the firebase cloud function? But then i would need to access both my own credentials and the new user credentials at same time. Is that even possible?

```
exports.testfunc = (req, res) => {
const customClaims = {
  moderator: true,
  subscription: true
};
const newUser = {
    moderator: req.body.role,
    subscription: true,
    company: req.body.company //Want to set this one to the creators company. For example if my company is named Awsome inc then the new user gets the same. 
}

return admin
  .auth()
  .getUserByEmail(req.body.email)
  .then(userRecord => {
    db.doc(`/usr/${userRecord.uid}`).update(customClaims); //Updates the user doc
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, customClaims); //Setting the custom claims
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Successfully updated `);
    return res.status(201).json("Success");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
  });
```

};

Is there any better way to achieve this? Any thoughts about this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), you could use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). With a Callable Cloud Function "Firebase Authentication and FCM tokens, when available, **are automatically included in requests**”, as indicated in the doc.

So, firstly, each user should have a Claim which holds the value of its Company name.

Then, in your Cloud Function, you just need to read the Claims of the moderator user calling the Callable Cloud Function (i.e. creating the new user) and extract its company name. Then it is just a matter of assigning the same company name in the corresponding "company" claim of the new user.

So, something along the following lines would do the trick:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  try {

        //Checking that the user calling the Cloud Function is authenticated
        if (!context.auth) {
            throw new Error('The user is not authenticated. Only authenticated Admin users can create new users.');
        }

        //Checking that the user calling the Cloud Function is a Moderator user
        const callerUid = context.auth.uid;  //uid of the user calling the Cloud Function
        const callerUserRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(callerUid);

        if (!callerUserRecord.customClaims.moderator) {
            throw new Error('Only Moderator users can create new users.');
        }

        const companyName = callerUserRecord.customClaims.companyName;

        //Use companyName to assign a Claim to the new user, as you do in your question
        const customClaims = {
          editor: true,  
          subscription: true,
          companyName: companyName
        };

        //....
        return ....

    } catch (error) {
            //....
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);

    }


});
```

---

You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents how to build, with a Callable Cloud Function, a module for allowing end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users (disclaimer, I'm the author). The all concept is very similar to your use case (and it uses and explains into detail the same code as above).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. The article was very helpful indeed. I will give it a try tonight.

Comment: It is up and running now!.Thank you very much for your help!